# Calling a custom container in GTM/GA4 with datalayer

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

maybe a dumb question, however i kinda stuck in here.

I created a trigger to all clicks with the ClickElement equals to css class, everything works, and the information arrives to GTM correctly.
However the information arrives at GTM like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "gtm.click",
  gtm.element: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/: html > body.page-template-d" +
               "efault.page.page-id-454.lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ",
  gtm.elementClasses: "elementor-item",
  gtm.elementId: "",
  gtm.elementTarget: "",
  gtm.elementUrl: "https://url.com/url/",
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 13
})
```

i would like to receive this variables with a diferent name in "event", and to set the variables inside the "comp_page" thing

```
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'menu_click',
    comp_page: {
        position: 'Top Menu',
        main_category: 'elementor-item',
        selected_category: 'https://url.com/url/"'
    }
});
```

I dont know if i was clear, any question please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event in the tag manager that would be triggered by a click on an element. If you have access to the site it's easy. If not, then you need to use a custom HTML tag and use it to add an event listener to create a dataLayer when you click on an element.

```
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
if(btn) {
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
dataLayer.push({
    event: 'menu_click',
    comp_page: {
        position: 'Top Menu',
        main_category: 'elementor-item',
        selected_category: 'https://url.com/url/"'
    }
});
})
}
```

And then in TagManager you can use the trigger "custom event"  - menu_click and get dataLayer variable into TagManager and send them as event parameters.